# Objective-C: Download 40 files

Tags: ios, objective-c, download

I have `tableView` and 40 cells. If user clicks on a cell, it is checked (the file exists or not). If the file does not exist, it starts downloading.

Question:

If user wants to download all 40 files at once my app will fail or lag if I use this code?

Code to download a 1 file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if (indexPath.row == 1) {
                     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                     NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.mp3"];
                     BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:false];
                     if (!fileExists) {

                         UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                                                       alertControllerWithTitle:@"1"
                                                       message:@"1"
                                                       preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
                         UIAlertAction* actionAdd = [UIAlertAction
                                                     actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                                     {
                                                         [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                                         _url1 =[NSURL URLWithString:@"link"];
                                                         _downloadTask1 = [_session downloadTaskWithURL:_url1];
                                                         [_downloadTask1 resume];

                                                         self.circularPV1 = [[FFCircularProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24)];

                                                         [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = self.circularPV1;
                                                         [self.view addSubview:_circularPV1];

                                                         [_circularPV1 startSpinProgressBackgroundLayer];

                                                     }];

                         UIAlertAction* actionCancel = [UIAlertAction
                                                        actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                        style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                        handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                                        {
                                                            [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                        }];
                         [alert addAction:actionAdd];
                         [alert addAction :actionCancel];
                         alert.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
                         alert.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 3.4, self.view.bounds.size.height / 4.0, 1.0, 1.0);
                         [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
                     }
                     if (fileExists) {
                         [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"Segue" sender: self];
                     }
                 }
}
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{

    if (downloadTask == _downloadTask1) {

        _paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        _documentsDirectory1 = [_paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSURL *newLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@/1.mp3", _documentsDirectory1]];
        NSError *error;
        [fileManager copyItemAtURL:location toURL:newLocation error:&error];
    }
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten  totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
{
    if( downloadTask == _downloadTask1){

        self.p1 = (float) totalBytesWritten;
        self.p2 = (float) totalBytesExpectedToWrite;

        [_circularPV1 setProgress:(p2 / p2)];
        [_circularPV1 stopSpinProgressBackgroundLayer];


    }
```

Comment: Try to use another thread for reading or writing files.

Comment: I should add `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
});` ?

Comment: Use an own (background) operation queue and `NS(Block)Operation` to download the files. For example look at [this Apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: @user yes, you can use `GCD` or as @vadian commented.

Comment: Yes, background or at least asynchronous downloading is recommended, because it can can be some time when application is unresponsive (changing view controller makes previous one not responding). Making long task (especially - with weak connection to Internet) in `viewWillApperar` can even crash application. In this case - next cell will be waiting for previous to load, creating visible lag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have a problem with 40 simultaneous downloads causing problems. `NSURLSession` is designed to manage multiple downloads. It will only actually download a few at a time and the rest will wait.

Vadian's recommendation to use a background operation to do the downloading is pointless. Your code is already using `NSURLSession`, which manages its own queues to do the download in the background. Ignore his comment. He's mistaken.

`NSURLSession` also calls it's delegate methods from the background, so you code for moving files is also being done from the background.

The problem you're going to have is that your `didWriteData` method is updating the UI. As said above, `NSURLSession` calls it's delegate methods from the background, so those UI calls are being done on a background thread, which is not allowed. You need to wrap any UIKit calls you make from your `NSURLSession` delegate methods in calls to the main thread. Like this, for example:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask 
  didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten  
  totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten 
  totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
{
    if( downloadTask == _downloadTask1){

        self.p1 = (float) totalBytesWritten;
        self.p2 = (float) totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
        //Make the UI calls below on the main thread.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue) {
            [_circularPV1 setProgress:(p2 / p2)];
            [_circularPV1 stopSpinProgressBackgroundLayer];
        }
    }
}
```

The code that begins with the **if** statement

```
if (indexPath.row == 1) {
```

Is floating outside of any method, which does not make sense. Where is that code supposed to live?

Comment: `if (indexPath.row == 1) {` supposed to live in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I add code in question

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)startDownloadwithURL:(NSURL*)url{


   if (_isUsed) {
     dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self startDownloadwithURL:url];
        return;

    });
  }
  _downloadTask1 = [_session downloadTaskWithURL:url];
  [_downloadTask1 resume];

}
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{

if (downloadTask == _downloadTask1) {
    _isUsed = NO;

    _paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    _documentsDirectory1 = [_paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *newLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@/1.mp3", _documentsDirectory1]];
    NSError *error;
    [fileManager copyItemAtURL:location toURL:newLocation error:&error];
 }
}
```

try this code to download. call startDownloadwithURL:(NSURL*)url where you start you downloading

Comment: There is no point in delaying new downloads like that. NSURLSession is set up to manage large numbers of downloads. It will only run a few downloads at a time (I want to say 3) and the rest will wait.

Comment: there is no point to down vote the answer if the answer is wrong then you can but this solution is also right not wrong

Comment: Your answer provides misleading information and suggests to a novice that they do something that is needlessly complex and has no benefit. It won't do active harm, but it doesn't do anything useful.